# How does chef-client in daemon mode behave

Tags: chef-infra

Chef-client when run in daemon mode would apply the run_list after regular intervals periodically, or would apply it only when the recipes/cookbooks in the run_list are updated over chef-server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The run_list will be executed periodically no matter if the recipes/cookbooks are updated on the chef-server.

Answer (score 2):

Chef-client in daemon mode would run chef-client in regular intervals.
To set interval you can use `-i` flag.

Generally chef is made to work in pull mode, not push, although there is some tools that can mimic that too.

From man page:

```
-d, --daemonize
          Indicates that the executable will be  run  as  a  daemon.  This
          option  is  only available on machines that run in UNIX or Linux
          environments. For machines that are  running  Microsoft  Windows
          that require similar functionality, use the chef-client::service
          recipe        in        the        chef-client         cookbook:
          http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/chef-client.   This  will
          install a chef-client service under Microsoft Windows using  the
          Windows Service Wrapper.

-i SECONDS, --interval SECONDS
          The frequency (in seconds) at which the chef-client  runs.  This
          value  is  configured  for the chef-client application run time,
          rather than in Chef::Config. Default value: 1800.
```